# Error in bash script while trying to execute command stored in variable

Tags: bash

I'm trying to run a bash script in background (`scanip.sh`), by calling it in another script (`stats.sh`). This is the `stats.sh` script:

```
#!/bin/bash

ifaces=("eth0" "eth1")
scripts_folder="~/comm"
conf_file="~/comm/conf"

scanip=(nohup "$scripts_folder"/scanip.sh "$conf_file" "${ifaces[0]}" &>/dev/null &)

"${scanip[@]}"
```

I was storing the `scanip` command (which calls `scanip.sh`) in a variable, as an array, and tried to execute it with the last line.
But everytime I try to run, the output is:

```
./stats.sh: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `&>'
./stats.sh: line 7: `scanip=(nohup "$scripts_folder"/scanip.sh "$conf_file" "${ifaces[0]}" &>/dev/null &)'
```

What is the issue here? How should I structure this script?

Comment: What should  `&>` do? I tThink you should only remove the `&`

Comment: Don't use `&>`. The `>file 2>&1` is [preferred](https://wiki-dev.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete).

Comment: Arrays can work for storing a command and its arguments, but not redirects (or pipes or multiple commands with delimiters or...). Those get parsed before variable (and array) references get expanded. Is there any reason you're trying to store the command, instead of just executing it directly?

Comment: If you do need to store the command, read [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050). Do NOT use `eval`; that way lies madness and really weird bugs.

Comment: @GordonDavisson I actually don't need to store the command. However, if in the script I substitute the last 2 lines with just `nohup "$scripts_folder"/scanip.sh "$conf_file" "${ifaces[0]}" &>/dev/null &` the scanip.sh is not executed (no errors, just returns and does not launch the script). And that's why I was trying this approach. @KamilCuk I've used that version also, still not working.

Comment: @imll are you sure that isn't just because you have "~" in quotes?

Comment: @picklerick, well, it's working now... I thought there was no problem in quoting twice (in variable initialization and in the command). Guess I won't forget this ever again.

Comment: @imll the problem is just with quoting of `~` specifically, though, using `$HOME` would be fine -- see [tilde expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Tilde-Expansion)